# Java script event to catch do you want to save this file promt in IE9

Tags: javascript, java, primefaces, jsf-2.2, primefaces-extensions

I am using prime *faces 6.0*.

I am exporting data to excel using *primefaces* extension `<pe:exporter>`. I have command button on click of this command button a progress bar dialog is opened. I want to implement in such a way once the "**Do you want to save this file  promt**" is appeared the progress bar should close.

Is there any event to do so?

Comment: I don't really understand your question, but you could combine onclick with javasctipt... like onclick="if ( !confirm("text") ) { return false; }"

Comment: I have around 20000 records. i have one command button inside a form. on click of which my data gets exported to excel. i am using primefaces extension <pe:exporter > to achieve this functionality. On complete of exporting the data in IE browsers we get prompt from the browsers " Do you want to save this file save,download and cancel". Now i want to implement the prorgress bar functionality to show user my data is getting export kind of user feedback.how to achieve this functionality? I can see there is no event to detect that prompt coming from the browser to complete the progress bar.

Answer (score 0):

On the server: create a custom Exporter ([how to](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/sections/exporter/customExporter.jsf)); when exporting, add to the response some custom cookie, signifying the end of the download.

On the client: create a script, that would periodically check for your custom cookie. When you see the cookie, close the dialog with the `PF('dialogWidgetVar').hide()` call.

The cookie stuff is basically how p:fileDownload does it internally, see the "Monitor status" paragraph for "FileDownload" in the user guide.